# JavaScript function giving an error saying

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am defining this function in JavaScript and I am getting an error like `'myobj is undefined'` in firefox and chrome. How do I define a function argument? Where did i go wrong ? I am not even calling it and I wonder why i am getting an error. JsLint is not showing any error.

```
function makeBox (myobj) {
    if( myobj.fullname.length > 18 ) {
        myobj.fullname = myobj.fullname.slice(0 ,15 );
        myobj.fullname = myobj.fullname + '...';
    }
    var box = templates.box.supplant(myobj);
    return box;
}
```

Comment: what does the call site look like?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the function?

Comment: It works for me (it doesn't say myobj is undefined). It says templates is undefined instead but that's because you didn't supply what templates is supposed to be.

Comment: @David: `templates` might be higher up in his scope chain...

Comment: I tried running the code on `node.js`. It reported no error. I wonder why browsers are giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `makeBox`, you have to supply it with an object as its argument:

```
var anObject = { fullname: 'Someone with a name' }

makeBox(anObject);
```

Otherwise, `myobj` within your function will be `undefined`.

Comment: I found the error. I was getting null results from the database which caused such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code is completely valid provided "templates" is defined and you supply the argument "myobj" as an object:

```
function makeBox(myobj) {
    if (myobj.fullname.length > 18) {
        myobj.fullname = myobj.fullname.slice(0, 15);
        myobj.fullname = myobj.fullname + '...';
    }
    var box = templates.box.supplant(myobj);
    return box;
}
makeBox({
    fullname: "Jason Smith"
});
```